# ld: library not found for -lstdc++ but no reference to lstdc++

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ld

Trying to build an older mac project with xcode 10. Link fails with the following error:
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm not using c++ in the project but I can't find any reference to lstdc in the project settings.

TIA for any pointers.

Comment: Build Settings/Linking/Other linker flags: It doesn't appear there?

Comment: Thanks but no. Nothing there.